# Console login, no password prompt => from user prompt to user prompt

Tags: buildroot

I have created my own "simple" Buildroot Linux.
"simple" means that there is currently nothing in the overlay directory that changes any configuration.
When the system is booted up, it will ask for the username.
i type: root [enter]

The system needs a moment and then asks for the username again. The password promt is missing.

the root password is set in the buildroot configuration.
because nothing has been changed by hand, i think the failure must be in the buildroot configuration or in the kernel configuration. but i have no idea..
are there any dependencies on agetty in relation to systemd?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share somewhere the root filesystem image that Buildroot has produced, so that the issue can be investigated further ?